# Where is the backspace button on a MacBook keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I need to know where is the back space in a MacBook Pro keyboard. I am new to the Mac, and not familiar with the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>delete</kbd> button is the equivalent of backspace on Windows, while <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> is the equivalent of the Windows delete.

Comment: Ok then what is the Mac equivalent for the Delete button in Windows ?

Comment: fn + delete. I've updated the answer.